# Who writes the descriptions on Netflix?

Tags: netflix

Netflix has short descriptions of the films, TV series, and TV episodes in its listings.

Who writes those? Are they supplied by the studio or does someone at Netflix write them?

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess is interns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to someone who answered a similar question over at Quora, the studios are probably providing the description along with base metadata, and no one at Netflix is tidying it up:

https://www.quora.com/How-are-Netflix-descriptions-written

> I used to be a designer there and I also worked for Ascent Media doing metadata for studios who stored their video files with them. From what I understood, studios deliver (or instruct their offsite file storage companies like Ascent to deliver) digital files and any associated metadata the facility had in regards to it. When I was at Ascent, the metadata associated with the titles was geared so that the files could be identified and filed properly, but associated descriptions were rarely any good since they were so numerous and were never touched by metadata processors, prioritizing the ID numbers over whether or not every episode of Sanford & Son and Soap had an artful and clever description. From what I can tell, its that kind of metadata where Netflix gets the initial descriptions for the volume titles, since they were comparably bad at Ascent and too numerous to hand-check without being flagged first.